# website not loading on IOS, Why do I get "The Site can't be reached" response?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, amazon-elb

I have a wordpress site working fine on Windows and android.  However it doesn't work on ios (Safari or Chrome).

I've tried the usual clearing cache / running in cognito mode and still no luck.   This is an image from an emulator in chrome (The same as what I am getting on a physical device):

[image: emulator]

It sits behind an AWS ELB.  There is a listener on port 80 that just does a redirect to port 443.   If I remove this then the site displays with no problem albeit unsecure on port 80.  The redirect works fine on windows and Mac desktop and also on Android.  So I think the problem is a certificate issue but I just dont know what else to do.  The certificate is being marked as perfectly valid everywhere else it is being used.

I've even tried on multiple ios devices and I get the same problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: what I also find strange is that the message doesn't include the web address.  ie, "The webpage at ..."

Comment: For more information, when I try to refresh the page shown above I get an about:blank page.   I've changed DNS server to 8.8.8.8 but still no luck